# Common Primes..............

Tags: prime-numbers, sagemath

In SageMath, the software, I was trying to create a visualization of how common it is for a number to be prime. Can anyone help me with the code? I am a super beginner and lost. I was going to post the question on Sage but the response time is so slow. So anyone who is familiar with Sage, you help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read about the prime number theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: A large number x has probability about $\frac{1}{ln(x)}$, that it is prime.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things I use in class about this, though I'm not sure if it answers your question of "how common".  Your question is somewhat vague.

```
@interact
def _(n=100):
    show(plot(prime_pi,3,n,color='black',legend_label='$\pi(x)$')+plot(x/ln(x),3,n,color='red',legend_label='$x/\ln(x)$')+plot(Li,3,n,color='green',legend_label='$Li(x)$'))

@interact
def _(n=100):
   P = plot(prime_pi,3,n,color='black',legend_label='$\pi(x)$')
   P += plot(Li,3,n,color='green',legend_label='$Li(x)$')
   P += plot(lambda x: Li(x)-sqrt(prime_pi(x)),3,n,color='orange',legend_label='$Li(x)-\sqrt{\pi(x)}$')
   P += plot(lambda x: Li(x)-.5*Li(sqrt(x)),3,n,color='red',legend_label='$Li(x)-\\frac{1}{2}Li(\sqrt{x})$')
   P += plot(lambda x: Li(x)-sqrt(x)/ln(x),3,n,color='purple',legend_label='$Li(x)-\sqrt{x}/\ln(x)$')
   show(P,xmin=max(n-1000,0),ymin=prime_pi(max(n-1000,0)))
```